# Release application always crashing on splash screen

Tags: android, ios, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I'm facing an issue with React Native release builds.  Either on iPhone or Android, my application works fine in debug mode, but after building with release configuration, the app always crashes on the splash screen.

On Android, I'm getting an OutOfMemory in the log triggered by WebSocketReader.java. Here is the Android log :

```
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.schooltoring, PID: 5893
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 10628794 byte allocation with 4409280 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:79)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:207)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at okio.Buffer.readString(Buffer.java:620)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at okio.Buffer.readUtf8(Buffer.java:591)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.readMessageFrame(WebSocketReader.java:222)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.processNextFrame(WebSocketReader.java:101)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.loopReader(RealWebSocket.java:262)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:201)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
07-26 10:57:18.639  5893  7623 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Complete log : https://gist.github.com/SLedunois/7d801cb0e55f2ae98bdbc054b0a84e61 (Sorry about the link. Crash report are too long to be included in the body)

On iPhone, I don't really understand the crash report. I'm new at iOS development. Here is the iOS crash report :

https://gist.github.com/SLedunois/76eaa85dfebb2ceff1f97cb4723989f1

I think, the error is caused by :

```
Thread 12 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001815192ec __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ba288 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 376
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181487d0c abort + 140
3   Schooltoring                    0x0000000100ccc734 0x100c78000 + 345908
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a931c8 __handleUncaughtException + 828
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180c4c8c8 _objc_terminate+ 35016 () + 112
6   Schooltoring                    0x0000000100cb090c 0x100c78000 + 231692
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180c3d37c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 111484 ()) + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180c3cccc __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func+ 109772 (_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180c4c720 _objc_exception_destructor+ 34592 (void*) + 0
10  Schooltoring                    0x0000000100d61af0 0x100c78000 + 957168
11  Schooltoring                    0x0000000100d61638 0x100c78000 + 955960
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181384aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181384a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018138e9b4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018138f2fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018138fcc8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181398098 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816b7e70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816b7b08 start_wqthread + 4
```

All my builds are configured to be signed.

Does someone face a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to your manifest under application:

Ex. `<application android:label="YourApp" android:largeHeap="true"></application>`

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for reply. I already test with the largeHeap option and I'm still facing the issue.

Comment: I don't really understand why React native in release is calling a class called "WebSocket".

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. The error was triggered because of the static image used in the application were too big.

See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images for more explanations.